# Is there an function which is called when a swipe is completely finished?

Tags: android

I am looking for a way to change the content of a fragment as soon as the fragment has completely disappeared from the display through the swipe.

I know how to change the content of a fragment, but I do not know how to get the timing right. 
So far, I change the content whenever the page is still disappearing. But it should change only when it has completely disappeared.

Is there a function called after the transaction is completely finished?

Comment: What do you mean through a swipe? Is it in a ViewPager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [viewpager's onPagedChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener) . It gets called whenever a swipe occurs.

Comment: I tried the function 'onPageSelected', this did not work. But 'setNextItemIfNeeded' worked. Thank you!